# How to center an unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to center an unordered list of unknown width, while still keeping the list-items left aligned.

Achieve the same result as this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { text-align: center; }
ul { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
```

Except my `<ul>` doesn't have a parent div. `ul { margin: 0 auto; }` doesn't work because I don't have a fixed width. `ul { text-align: center; }` doesn't work because the list-items won't be left aligned anymore. So how can I center this `<ul>` while keeping the `<li>`s left aligned (without having a parent div wrapper)?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**: Perhaps my wording wasn't the best... The first block of code already works... what i need is to do it **without** the `<div>` wrapper, if that's possible of course. Float tricks? Pseudo element tricks? There must be a way.

Comment: You have to set the width of `ul` and `li` in order to let browser know how to center the content.

Comment: have a look on your code, http://jsfiddle.net/fNFYr/

Comment: Yes, I would like that result, but without the parent <div>.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>56456456</li>
    <li>4564564564564649999999999999999999999999999996</li>
    <li>45645</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

## list-style-position:inside

This may not match your exact requirements, but it still very useful:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answers another question, which is "how to center the symbols/bullets of a centered UL list". OP's question is how to center the ul contents themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say the list is:

```
<ul>
 <li>item1</li>
 <li>item2</li>
 <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

For this example.
If I understand correctly, you want the list items to be in the middle of the screen, but you want the text IN those list items to be centered to the left of the list item itself. Doing that is actually pretty easy. You just need some CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And it works! Here is what is happening. First, we say we want to affect only unordered lists. Then, we do Rafael Herscovici's trick for centering the list items. Finally, we say to align the text to the left of the list items.

Answer (score 3):

To center align an unordered list, you need to use the CSS text align property. In addition to this, you also need to put the unordered list inside the div element.

Now, add the style to the div class and use the text-align property with center as its value.

See the below example.

```
<style>
.myDivElement{
    text-align:center;
}
.myDivElement ul li{
   display:inline;

 }
</style>
<div class="myDivElement">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the reference website [Center Align Unordered List](https://tutorialdeep.com/knowhow/center-align-unordered-list-inside-div-css/)

Answer (score -2):

In case the dots are stuck on the left side while the text is aligned on the center. You can remove the "ul" from the script.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
    <style>
        div.list {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    
    <body>
        <div class="list">
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it sure will work. But is a serious anti-pattern and is strongly advised for everybody to follow Semantic HTML structures. The same effect can be achieved by using the CSS property `list-style: none` on `ul` or `ol` tags.