# How to center ul list with css?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i have been messing with CSS but cant get desired results.

I made simple list with url & thumbnails in html and styled it with CSS.

I cant get list into center of page. I want it to be even from both sides, but its more on the right side of page.

Can someone help me with this issue please.

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: #151924;
}
ul#playlist
{
text-align: center;
}
ul#playlist li
{   
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    background: #323B55;
    border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px
}
ul#playlist li img 
{
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
ul#playlist h3 
{
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul#playlist li a
{
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #b2b2b2
}
```

> ```
>   <title>Playlist test</title>
>     <body> <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="playlist">
> <li><a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
> <li>      <a href="http://hls01-09.az.myvideo.az/hls-live/livepkgr/foxturk/foxturk/foxturk.m3u8?mfamwuUL6IpOXDJ8WwxJ">
>   <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2790/5864018592_65d4a0a298.jpg">
>   <h3>Star TV</h3>
>   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></a></li>
>
>
>
>
>
>   </ul> </body>
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yos5231/

Comment: By any chance, have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443013/how-to-center-an-unordered-list?

Answer (score 2):

`#playlist` ul inherit 50px **left padding** (available for the hidden li bullets).

You have to reset it `#playlist { padding 0; }` or add the **padding** value you need to equal center the content `#playlist { padding 0 50px; }`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7yos5231/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#playlist
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding : 0 20px;/* change to the value you desire.*/
}
```