# Positioning list of text items to center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify a theme of my website. All the content is center aligned already.

In this regard, I want to align a list of text items to the center. Below is the CSS, which I am using:

```
.recent_news_css {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For easier understanding, I draw a red color border around the parent of this div class too. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the page]

I am surprised to see the text and bullet point symbols aren't center. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Here is the same problem and solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443013/how-to-center-an-unordered-list

Comment: If its still not solvable, please provide a fiddle/pen link

Comment: ^^^ or update your question with relevant HTML sample

Comment: @Panther and Wh1T3h4Ck5: Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4cvg5bk/). The HTML is generated by Drupal Framework. Hence it is too big. I really apologize for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin:0 auto;` instead of auto. It will work.

```
.recent_news_css {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
border: 3px solid green;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Actually, there are no changes in UI, even after using `margin:0 auto`.

Comment: both ways set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. top and bottom margins in this case are irrelevant so doesn't matter is value of `margin` property `auto` or `0 auto`

Comment: Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4cvg5bk/). The HTML is generated by Drupal Framework. Hence it is too big. I really apologize for it the long HTML and CSS. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think the `li` needs to take all space try

```
li{
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I added following CSS. `.recent-news-css {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css ul{
    text-align: center;
}
`
**Unfortunately, it didn't work.**
Please see screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dgmklfeu70r2er/css.png?dl=0)

This time, I can't see the bullet point symbols.

Comment: within ur screenshot u didn't add `text-align:center;` to ur li css

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7r517hd47q0hvzb/new_li.png?dl=0)

Comment: Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4cvg5bk/). The HTML is generated by Drupal Framework. Hence it is too big. I really apologize for it. I believe some CSS attributes are interfering with each other. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ul#views-ticker-vTicker-list-recent_news` remove position : absolute, that is all within ur inline style

Comment: It seems difficult to remove this style since it is directly generated by the framework. Can you suggest any workaround to do the same? I can add extra CSS easily. I realized that `position : absolute` is necessary for this item. Since it is a vertical scrolling text. `position : absolute` shows the moving animation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for somithing like this?

```
#parent{
  border: 3px solid red;
  width:500px;
}

.recent_news_css {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35%;
}


<body>
  <div id="parent">
      <ul class="recent_news_css">
        <li>
          some Text
        </li>
        <li>
           some Text
        </li>
        <li>
          some Text
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm3qh3h8/

Comment: I added following CSS. `.recent-news-css {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css ul{
    text-align: center;
}
`
**Unfortunately, it didn't work.**
Please see screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dgmklfeu70r2er/css.png?dl=0)

Comment: Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4cvg5bk/). The HTML is generated by Drupal Framework. Hence it is too big. I really apologize for it the long HTML and CSS. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

because you make a div to text-align:center.

It is impossible.You shoud add style "text-align:center" on li tag.

Like this,see image below

[image]

```js
.view-content ul li{
   text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: I added following CSS. `.recent-news-css {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent-news-css ul{
    text-align: center;
}
`
**Unfortunately, it didn't work.**
Please see screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dgmklfeu70r2er/css.png?dl=0)

Comment: Here is the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4cvg5bk/). The HTML is generated by Drupal Framework. Hence it is too big. I really apologize for it the long HTML and CSS. Thank you very much.