# Can't get list in sidebar to center vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my unordered list within my sidebar but none of the following solutions applied to my CSS have worked:

```
align-items: center;
vertical-align: middle;
transform: translateY(-50%);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

I'm feeling very stuck at this point and would appreciate your solutions. Here is my SCSS and HTML:

```css
  
$font-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
$body-bg: rgb(240, 230, 230);
$sidebar-bg: rgb(255, 210, 235);
$text: black;
$shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px rgb(207, 207, 207);

body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed */
  
  background-color: $body-bg;
  color: $text;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: $sidebar-bg;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;

  -moz-box-shadow: $shadow; /*hor-length shadodow-start-point shadow-depth darkness */
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
  box-shadow: $shadow;

  * {
    text-align: center;
  }

  ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> <!--Makes mobile viewing good-->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <h1 class="display-3 pt-4 pb-4">DRIP</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Finances</li>
          <li>Development</li>
          <li>DIY</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery, Popper, Bootstrapper JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have the list centered inside relative to the sidebar it's in (if that makes sense). Even when I add styling such as padding between the UL items or add more UL items, I want it to remain centered in the sidebar. Sadly none of my solutions have affected the list how I wanted them to.

Comment: You can try adding `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: table;` to your `<ul>` tag. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443013/how-to-center-an-unordered-list

Comment: @KiprasBielinskas Tried that just now and caused no change :(

Comment: Then maybe your actual code is a bit different than in your question, because running your code and applying css, `<ul>` element does go to the center of your container [see the image](https://ibb.co/wSDpgGs)

Comment: The code does properly center my list horizontally, but I'd like to center it vertically (which is the issue).

Please keep in mind the CSS I posted is in SCSS syntax and that there is a colored background to help you visualize the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `div` around the content of the sidebar. Make the sidebar a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and align the item (newly created div) in the center vertically.

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div>
      <h1 class="display-3 pt-4 pb-4">DRIP</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Finances</li>
        <li>Development</li>
        <li>DIY</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution did in fact move my list to the vertical center of my sidebar, but it also pushes down my heading ("DRIP").

I'd like to keep the heading fixed to where it is although I'm not sure how.  https://imgur.com/EXRVuag

Comment: @Sam Maybe you get what you want when you move the `h1` outside the sidebar.

Comment: That causes the <h1> to load before the sidebar causing this visual: https://imgur.com/yeRKjFh

I'm sorry I feel very lost haha.