# align unordered list to the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have tried and researched many ways but I couldn't find out how to align unordered list in center. it seems like the bullets are not connected to the text and stay still.
here is the html code:

```
<ul id="facts">
  <li>fact 1</li>
  <li>fact 2</li>
  <li>fact 3</li>
</ul>
```

and this is the css code:

```
#facts {
  text-align: center;
}
```

the result will be like [image: this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an unordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443013/how-to-center-an-unordered-list)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks but it didn't help me out.

Comment: i just use this code to your example and work..

Comment: No idea. It is a little bit complicated since I just finished css today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list-style-position: inside;` to set the bullets in front of the text like this:

```css
#facts {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul id="facts">
  <li>fact 1</li>
  <li>fact 2</li>
  <li>fact 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is a duplicate question

Comment: But it offers a different solution anyway, that is not available in the other Q. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks man it helped. Needed something simple like this :)

Comment: @AI.G. Simple add this answer to other question and not always open same question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `Unordered List` in an element with the class of `.container` and define `.container` like this:

```css
.container{
      width:100%;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>   
    <li>Ipsum</li>  
    <li>Dolor</li>      
    <li>Set</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution.